# Add a control using XAML but instantiated using code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, instantiation

I'm trying to understand how XAML and code-behind talk to each other. I know that code-behind can access an element instantiated in XAML using the Name attribute eg:

Instantiate the button in XAML:

```
<SomeControlParent controlParent>
<Button Name=button1/>
<SomeControlParent controlParent>
```

Change properties of the button in code-behind:

```
button1.Content = "I created this button in XAML"
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do the opposite using XAML eg:

Instantiate the button in code-behind:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
controlParent.Child.Add(button1);
```

and then change the Content of the button using XAML.

Thanks!
Soumaya

Comment: +1  Newbies sometimes ask the most interesting questions.  It sounds like a basic one, but the answer is more complex than you'd initially think.  But that's XAML for ya.  There's a lot of new concepts to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Having a code-behind lets you reference elements that have x:Name defined on them in XAML.  Going the other direction, you can define properties on your UserControl and then reference them in XAML using a RelativeSource binding:

```
{Binding MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

So in your example, you could have a property on your UserControl (although you'd probably want it to be a dependency property so you have change notification):

```
public Button Button1 { get; private set; }
```

And then insert it into your XAML using:

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding Button1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hey, I changed the name in XAML!"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way. I added public Button Button1 { get; private set; } in the partial class that defines the window, and then <ContentControl Content="{Binding Button1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/> to the XAML but no luck...

Comment: Make Button1 into a dependency property as I mentioned.  The easiest way to create one is type propdp then hit the tab key twice.

Comment: I did and VS tells me I'm not allowed to set the content twice. Maybe I should set the content control to some other property than Content on the first XAML line?

Comment: Oops. I forgot the enclosing <ContentControl.Resources> tags around the Style. I made the correction above.

Comment: Now it builds, but only if I use a CLR property, not a Dependency Property, and it looks completely empty, and it builds even if I use any text instead of Button1 after Binding ...

Comment: You should use a dependency property.  Yes, the bindings are not checked at compile-time.